# composer rest server behind aws api gateway

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I would appreciate with help on this. I watch a hyperledger comoposer tutorial where Zach Gollwitzer said there  are 2 options to secure the rest-server API of the business network, one was to put it behind an API Management gateway and the other with multi-user mode. I would like to know how I can export the Rest rever API To AWS API gateway. What file is used to do this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your rest server is started you should be able to 'hit'

http://localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json which describes the various API endpoints.

Hopefully this is enough for the AWS API gateway.